# React-Native: Mask image with a bottom radius

Tags: react-native, border, react-native-stylesheet

How do I make the border bottom radius in an image?

And how can I mask the image to the green area?

[image: Image here]

**I've tried the following codes, but I can't get the radius ratio in the image I've shared above**

View Code:

```
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
    <View style={styles.welcomeWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.welcomeImageWrapper}>
            <Image style={{width:'100%'}} source={require('../assets/images/test-slide.jpg')}/>
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
       <Text style={{marginBottom:50,fontSize:18,fontFamily:'Montserrat-Regular'}}>Deneme Text </Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Style Code:

```
wrapper:{
    flex:1,
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor:colors.white,
},
welcomeWrapper:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',   
    backgroundColor:colors.green01,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position:'relative',
    width:'100%',
    borderBottomRightRadius:Dimensions.get('window').width/100*50,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:Dimensions.get('window').width/100*50,
},
```

Comment: Please post your existing code and list what you've already tried

Comment: @JeremyLee I shared the existing codes..Thank you..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seeing the shape of your image mask, I think you should use something like `react-native-svg` to create a real image mask.

**Steps**:

1. Set the background image in a `View` with a `position: absolute`, so that your image is always in the background and can be masked
2. Add `react-native-svg` to your project, for instance with `yarn add react-native-svg`, and link the library using `react-native link`. Finally, re-launch the metro bundler and compile your app (`run-android` or `run-ios`).
3. Design the svg mask (I used [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape)) and add it to the container's `View`, the mask should have the same `backgroundColor` as your text container.
4. A bit of styling using react's `flexbox` layout to be able to have almost the same look on every device. In this example, the mask takes `5/6` of the screen height as my mask `flex` number is 5 and my text `flex` is 1

So, this is what I ended up with:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Path, Svg } from 'react-native-svg';

const mask = {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: 50,
  bgColor: '#ecf0f1',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  mask: {
    flex: 5,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: mask.bgColor,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
});

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./assets/image.jpg')} />
    <View style={styles.mask}>
      <Svg width={mask.width} height={mask.height}>
        <Path
          fill={mask.bgColor}
          d={`M 0 0 L 0 ${mask.height} L ${mask.width} ${mask.height} L ${mask.width} 0 A ${mask.width / 2} ${mask.height / 2} 0 0 1 ${mask.width / 2} ${mask.height / 2} A ${mask.width / 2} ${mask.height / 2} 0 0 1 0 0 z `} />
      </Svg>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Text</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);

export default App;
```

And here is the result in an `Android` emulator

[image: Result in android emulator]

Hope this helps!

Link to snack: https://snack.expo.io/BJlZgpuB7 (but my image does not load on snack :( )

Comment: Thank you very very much for this reply , descriptive, detailed and pretty nice.